# Find objects by multiple values in nested List object Hibernate, Jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have Student entity. Students have list of subjects in ManyToMany relationship. Something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_subject", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id"))
    private List<Subject> subjects ;
}
```

I want to get all students that contain any of the requested subjects in my repository, something like this:

```
List<Student> findBySubjects(List<Subject> requestedSubjects)
```

Is this the right way to go? If not, is it even possible to do it like this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Will do, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Query` annotation.

```
@Query("SELECT student FROM Student student INNER JOIN student.subjects subject WHERE subject IN (:subjects)")
List<Student> findBySubjects(@Param("subjects") List<Subject> requestedSubjects)
```

Comment: Hello, it is implemented. Will inform when I test it out. Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm! Went into depth a little bit with custom queries, have better knowledge of it now thanks to you! Mustache gracias :)